# Updating swiftui text view by a function in another file

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

I have a function that goes out to an API and gets a stock price. When I try to run the function `updateView()`, I just get 50 instead of 60 which is expected in the text view. The function `updateView()` can't change the text. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? My code is below.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var stockPrice: Double = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        List {
            HStack {
                Text("Stock Price (15 Min. delay)")
                Spacer()
                Text("\(stockPrice)")
                    .onAppear() {
                        self.updateStockPrice(stock: 50)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public func updateStockPrice(stock: Int) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { 
            DispatchQueue.main.async { 
                self.stockPrice = Double(stock)
            }
        }
    }
}

// Assume function updateView is in another file.
func updateView() {
    ContentView().stockPrice = 60.0
}
```

Comment: Calling `ContentView().stockPrice = 60.0` creates a new `ContentView` instance. You need to refer the same instance which is displayed (it is usually created in the `SceneDelegate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following three problems with your code:

1. As [pawello2222](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8697793/pawello2222) mentioned, you need to set `stockPrice` on the same `ContentView` object that is being displayed. You will find it either in your `AppDelegate` or `SceneDelegate`.
2. `@State` does not publish changes. You need a `@Published` variable in an `@ObservableObject`.
3. `onAppear()` gets called when the view is updated on binding variable change. And so, your value will get overwritten. You need to find another place to call `updateStockPrice()` - the view initializer perhaps.

The following code snippet works in Playground. But depending on your real-world context, you will have to fix the above problems appropriately.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var stockPrice: Double = 0.0
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()

    init() {
        self.updateStockPrice(stock: 50)
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            HStack {
                Text("Stock Price (15 Min. delay)")
                Spacer()
                Text("\(model.stockPrice)")
            }
        }
    }

    public func updateStockPrice(stock: Int) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.model.stockPrice = Double(stock)
            }
        }
    }
}

// Assume function updateView is in another file.
func updateView(_ view: ContentView) {
    view.model.stockPrice = 60.0
}

let view = ContentView()

updateView(view)

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(view)
```